# How can I integrate Python and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, brython, transcrypt, rapydscript

Is it possible to integrate Python and JavaScript?  For example, imagine you wanted to be able to define classes in JavaScript and use them from Python (or vice versa).  If so, what's the best way?  I'm interested not only if this is possible but if **anyone has done it within a "serious" project or product**.

I'm guessing it would be possible using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/) and [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), for one example, but I'm curious whether or not anyone's ever actually done this, and if there are solutions for other platforms (especially [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython)).

Comment: Perhaps you could compile CPython to JavaScript using Emscripten, and then run CPython in the browser. It might be possible to call Python functions from JavaScript, and vice versa. http://syntensity.com/static/python.html

Comment: @AndersonGreen this was already done: pypyjs - https://github.com/rfk/pypyjs

Comment: For what it's worth, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28652754/1519199) presents a unified approach to sharing objects between JS and Python, and is implemented in [this repo](https://github.com/jdthorpe/ajvpy) which simply wraps a NodeJS module bundled via webpack and exposes it as a Python Module.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's something, a Python wrapper around the SeaMonkey Javascript interpreter... http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey

Comment: This seems like the closest thing to what I was looking for; thanks.

Comment: An active spidermonkey library(https://github.com/Distributive-Network/PythonMonkey)

Answer (score 29):

How about [pyjs](http://pyjs.org/)?

From the above website:

> pyjs is a Rich Internet Application (RIA) Development Platform for both Web and Desktop. With pyjs you can write your JavaScript-powered web applications entirely in Python.

Comment: @AppleGrew Is it possible to run pyjamas entirely in the browser (without any server-side components)?

Comment: Note that pyjs does not support Python 3.0+ https://github.com/pyjs/pyjs/issues/831

Comment: `pyjs` is not maintained anymore (the last commit was on Sep 22, 2015).

Answer (score 17):

This question is not exactly young, but there have come up some alternatives:

- "[Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org) is an *entirely in-browser* implementation of Python."
- [Brython](https://www.brython.info) - "A Python 3 implementation for client-side web programming"
- [RapydScript](http://www.rapydscript.com) - "Python-like JavaScript without the extra overhead or quirks"
- [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) - "Lean and mean Python 3.6 to JavaScript compiler with multiple inheritance, sourcemaps, static type checking and selective operator overloading." (also [on Github](https://github.com/JdeH/Transcrypt))

Comment: Just to add my two cents, both Skulpt and Brython are toys rather than full-blown compilers/languages. RapydScript and Transcrypt will run circles around them performance-wise. In fact, the absence of performant Python interpreter in JS was the reason RapydScript was invented to begin with. RapydScript now has an added benefit of type safety, just like TypeScript.

disclaimer: I'm the RapydScript maintainer.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov I didn't have time to test those, so thanks for you additions :)

Comment: Transcrypt can be pip-installed, nice if you don't wish to immerse yourself in the js ecosystem. RapydScript however seems to be the quickest transpiled option as far as I gathered so far. A nice array of options is described [here](https://github.com/zoofIO/flexx/wiki/PyScript-vs-X). There is also [Jiphy](https://github.com/timothycrosley/jiphy) which seems unmaintained.

Answer (score 10):

there are two projects that allow an "obvious" transition between python objects and javascript objects, with "obvious" translations from int or float to Number and str or unicode to String: [PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8) and, as one writer has already mentioned: [python-spidermonkey](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey).

there are actually two implementations of pyv8 - the original experiment was by sebastien louisel, and the second one (in active development) is by flier liu.

my interest in these projects has been to link them to [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org), a python-to-javascript compiler, to create a JIT python accelerator.

so there is plenty out there - it just depends what you want to do.

Comment: pyv8 is still well-maintained, in contrast to almost all of the other ideas presented in the answers here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

If your just interested in sharing complex data types between javascript and python, check out [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html). It wraps the standard Python JSON libraries, but has some smarts in serializing and deserializing Python classes and other data types.

Quite a few Google App Engine projects have used this library.  [Joose](http://code.google.com/p/joose-js/) and [FirePython](http://github.com/darwin/firepython/tree/master) both incorporate jsonpickle.

Comment: Note that jsonpickle uses a non-standard "py/ref" reference type that makes it harder to use for non-python clients.  There's currently no way to turn it off.

http://code.google.com/p/jsonpickle/issues/detail?id=9

Answer (score 6):

Many of the examples are years out of date and involve complex setup. You can give [JSPyBridge](https://github.com/extremeheat/JSPyBridge/) a try (full disclosure: I'm the author).

It's a bi-directional bridge that lets you use JavaScript code from Python, and vice-versa. That means that Python code can call JS callbacks, and JS code can call Python callbacks.

Access Python from JS, numpy + matplotlib example, with the ES6 import system:

```js
import { py, python } from 'pythonia'
const np = await python('numpy')
const plot = await python('matplotlib.pyplot')

// Fixing random state for reproducibility
await np.random.seed(19680801)
const [mu, sigma] = [100, 15]
// Inline expression evaluation for operator overloading
const x = await py`${mu} + ${sigma} * ${np.random.randn(10000)}`

// the histogram of the data
const [n, bins, patches] = await plot.hist$(x, 50, { density: true, facecolor: 'g', alpha: 0.75 })
console.log('Distribution', await n) // Always await for all Python access
await plot.show()
python.exit()
```

Through CommonJS (without top level await):

```js
const { py, python } = require('pythonia')
async function main() {
  const np = await python('numpy')
  const plot = await python('matplotlib.pyplot')
  ...
  // the rest of the code
}
main().then(() => python.exit()) // If you don't call this, the process won't quit by itself.
```

Access JS from python:

```py
from javascript import require, globalThis

chalk, fs = require("chalk"), require("fs")

print("Hello", chalk.red("world!"), "it's", globalThis.Date().toLocaleString())
fs.writeFileSync("HelloWorld.txt", "hi!")
```

Answer (score 4):

[PyExecJS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS) is able to use each of PyV8, Node, JavaScriptCore, SpiderMonkey, JScript.

```
>>> import execjs
>>> execjs.eval("'red yellow blue'.split(' ')")
['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
>>> execjs.get().name
'Node.js (V8)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Js2Py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) to translate JavaScript to Python, this is the only tool available :)

Comment: Supports Python 3 now

Answer (score 2):

There's a bridge based on JavaScriptCore (from WebKit), but it's pretty incomplete:
http://code.google.com/p/pyjscore/

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out the PyPy project - they have a Python to (anything) compiler, including Python to Javascript, C, and llvm.  This allows you to write your code in Python and then compile it into Javascript as you desire.

http://codespeak.net/pypy

Also, check out the informative blog:

http://morepypy.blogspot.com/

Unfortunately though, you can't convert Javascript to Python this way.  It seems to work really well overall, they used to have a Javascript (made from compiled Python) version of the Bub'n'Bros game online (though the server has been down for a while).

http://bub-n-bros.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `XPCOM`, say in `XUL` based apps like Firefox, Thunderbird or Komodo.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with Pyjon some time ago and seems manage to write Javascript's eval directly in Python and ran simple programs... Although it is not complete implementation of JS and rather an experiment.
Get it here:

http://code.google.com/p/pyjon/

Answer (score 1):

Many of these projects mentioned above are dead or dying, lacking activity and interest from author side. Interesting to follow how this area develops.

For the record, in era of plugin based implementations, KDE camp had an attempt to solve this with plugin and non-language specific way and created the Kross https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kross_(software) - in my understanding it never took off even inside the community itself.

During this chicken and egg -problem time, javascript-based implementions are definately way to go. Maybe in the future we seee pure and clean, full Python support natively in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend you [pymport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pymport).

It allows for total compatibility of all Python code with Node.js, including the binary modules. Unlike the other solutions - and there are plenty - this one does not spawn a separate Python process. Both Python and Node.js co-exist in the same shared memory process and transition between the two is very fast. You can pass objects and functions. It is made for using Python libraries from Node.js, your main program must be Node.js.

```bash
npm install pymport
npx pympip3 install numpy
```

then simply in JavaScript:

```js
const { pymport, proxify } = require('pymport');
const np = proxify(pymport('numpy'));

const a = np.array([2, 3, 4]);
console.log(a.toString());
```

*(I am the author of this module)*