# ng-repeat not working with single object value in ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-init="items=[{'id':1,'name':'Amit'}]">
    <input type="text" size="40" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchString">{{ i.id }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Output :**

```
<div ng-init="items=[{'id':1,'name':'Amit'}]">
    <input type="text" size="40" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    <ul>
        <!-- ngRepeat: i in items | filter:searchString -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I use single key value then it's not working.But when I use multiple key value like: **[{'id':1,'name':'Amit'},{'id':2,'name':'Neeraj'}]** then it's working.
What is the mistake in my code.

Comment: it seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5595/

Comment: I voted to close this question due to the problem not being reproducible.  Also, this isn't an appropriate use for `ng-init`;  `ng-init` is intended for specialized usage where it is impossible to initialize the data in any other way, like in a controller for example.

Comment: @Claies I can't get data to app.js file.Controller can work when I use this in same page not in another js file.I'm using django framework that's symbol {{ }} is also same as angularJs

Comment: you can change the interpolation symbols for angular.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider#!/.  However, I'm not sure how that has anything to do with `ng-init`, and saying you can't use data in another js file doesn't make sense without more explanation.

Comment: @Claies this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331811/defining-django-context-variable-in-jquery-giving-me-error url will help for understanding we can't use django data in anotherjs file.If we want to use in js file you have to make a method in js and called from main page.

Comment: I think perhaps you are confused about what that post is suggesting.  You *definitely* can use multiple js files in django.  That being said, it's not even clear what that has to do with this not being an appropriate use for nginit

Answer (score 0):

As you have single key, you can directly access it using items. Id, and items.name

When you have multiple value, you can use ng-repeat for a loop. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

i double check this and its working

```
    <html>

<body ng-app="">

    <div ng-init="items=[{'id':1,'name':'Amit'}]">
        <input type="text" size="40" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchString">{{ i.id }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```