# how to return a dictionary in python django and view it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm returning this in my view:

```
    data = {'val1' : 'this is x', 'val2' : True}
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

I want to use this information in the dictionary within my javascript. Kind of like this:

```
            function(data) {
                if (data["val2"]) {
                    //success
                    alert(data["val1"]);
                }
            }
```

However my javascript doesn't work. There is no alert popping up and I know that the dictionary has the information when it leaves my python view.

**How can I read this information in my JS?**

---

Ok so the answer for the view is to simplejson.dumps(data).
Now when I do an alert(data) in my JS on my template I get **{'val1' : 'this is x', 'val2' : True}**.
Now how can I manage the 2nd part of the question which is read out the values like

```
        function(data) {
            if (data["val2"]) {
                //success
                alert(data["val1"]);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
The simplejson.dumps(data) converts th dictionary into string. So in the javascript you need to convert the string to an object.
THis is the easiest but apparently unsafe way.

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Python Data to JavaScript via Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445989/passing-python-data-to-javascript-via-django)

Comment: Even if you use Ajax, the answers in the above question will help you.

Comment: Are you using an AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) to make the request?

Comment: yes it's ajax and that question did help me understand that I must use jsdump in the view thanks. now i just want to know how to access the object in the template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Very simply:

```
import json
data = {'val1' : 'this is x', 'val2' : True}
return HttpResponse( json.dumps( data ) )
```

Comment: ok i have this back in the JS {'val1' : 'this is x', 'val2' : True}. Now how can I access just the specific values. Like val1? like this data["val1"]? I get an undefined when I try alert(data["val1"]);

Comment: Yes it still gives undefined :(

Answer (score 10):

JSON is easiest way to transfer data(also you can use XML).

In python:

```
    import json
    data = {'val1': "this is x", 'val2': True}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

In javascript:

```
    function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data["val2"]) {
            alert(data["val1"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, or instead specifying mimetype like in the answer of Shwetabh Sharan below

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly use the python object you have to convert it into JSON string first
Look into following documentation.

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html
also
http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the mimetype in HttpResponse

```
    return HttpResponse(
                        json.dumps({"status":False, "message":"Please enter a report name."}) ,
                        content_type="application/json"
                        )
```

Comment: As of Django 1.9, `mimetype` has been replaced with `content_type`