# javascript-readable json from python

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

My view computes a json and outputs a `json.dumps()`, and I'm passing this as the dictionary key `data`. I'm trying to pass this to a script element in my template, but when rendering, the browser gets it as a python-escaped string`{&quot;nodes&quot;: [{&quot;count&quot;:......` which isn't readable to the javascript. What I need is python to send it as a JS-escaped string, something like this `{"nodes": [{"count":......`.
I tried `str(data)` and `eval(data)` without success. Basically I need python to send the string just as if it were printing it to the console. Thanks

Comment: is this question of any help to you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1445989/92493

Comment: I believe that if you're rendering it to your HTML template and that this HTML template will be send to the browser using the mime type 'text/html' (or it's variant) than the browser will escape the quotes and such, so i think it really depend on the mime type that you're sending to the browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to use a json in a template.
In order to do that, you have to disable the escaping, for exemple like this.

```
{% autoescape off %}
var x={{json_var}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 12):

Note that instead of using

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ my_json }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

You can simply use a filter :

```
{{ my_json|safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'foo' : 'bar'}, ensure_ascii=False),
    mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: I use something like this when sending a simple HttpResponse, but in this case I had to render a template.

Comment: Np. Glad the answer was a simple one.