# Load json data for the first time request and to display the same in Home Page

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I am using Vue.js for the first time. I need to serialize the objects of django

> views.py

```
 def articles(request):
        model = News.objects.all() # getting News objects list
        modelSerialize =  serializers.serialize('json', News.objects.all())
        random_generator = random.randint(1,News.objects.count())    
        context = {'models':modelSerialize, 
                  'title' : 'Articles' , 
                  'num_of_objects' : News.objects.count() , 
                  'random_order' :  random.randint(1,random_generator) ,
                  'random_object' : News.objects.get(id = random_generator ) ,
                  'first4rec' : model[0:4],
                  'next4rec' : model[4:],
                  }
        return render(request, 'articles.html',context)
```

I have tried to display serialized json data in html its working fine there,

Now , how to intialize json data in vue instance and to access in html using v-repeat attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/kn9181/1yy84912/

Please can any one help???

Comment: from version 1.0+, v-repeat has been removed in favor of v-for. so this might be the problem

Comment: Thanks.I had changed to v-for now , but my question related to ,  how to pass serialized data json to js

Comment: i don't know python, but in php 
we would do things like, `var json = " <?php echo $json_string;?>"` to pass json data as string from php to js.
and  `var obj = JSON.decode(json);` to get js object.

Comment: didnot solve my problem.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445989/passing-python-data-to-javascript-via-django 

once you get js object containing data, you can pass the data to `Vue()`

Comment: What is your question ? do you want to initialise the blog objects in Vue instance or you want the like buttons to work ? I see two different questions when i look at the Jsfiddle and the bounty

Comment: @MevinBabu,First I want to initialise the json objects in vue instance data, then user can like the article which they like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example.

*views.py*

```
def articles(request):
    context {
        'articles' : ['a1','a2','a3']
    }
    return render(request, 'articles.html', context)
```

*articles.html*

```
{% verbatim %}
<div id="app">
    <ul>
     <li v-for="a in articles">{{ a }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}

<script>
    new Vue({
        el : "#app",
        data : function(){
            return {
                articles : {{ articles | safe }}
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Things to watch out for :

- The `verbatim` tag to stop Django from rendering the contents of this block tag since Vue uses the same interpolating symbols.
- The `safe` filter to prevent Django from escaping the contents.
- If you are passing a dictionary, consider turning it into JSON first

Generally speaking, prefer passing data to Vue via [Ajax](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource)