# How can I avoid this Unexpected token error when using django/javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to pass some data from my django app into a javascript following the
answers [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445989/passing-python-data-to-javascript-via-django)

**views.py**

```
context['username'] = json.dumps(request.user.username)
```

**test_script.js**

```
document.write('Script working')
username = {{ username|safe }};
```

But in *console* I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't use jinja2 in javascript. Simply create your js variable in your html in <javascript> tags, then place your script below and you can use that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    .
    .
    .
  </body>
  <script>
    var username = "{{ username|safe }}"
  </script>
  <script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Place your username variable in your html, then you can access it in your script file.

Comment: Tried document.write(username); and get error: Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

Comment: ```console.log(username)``` ?

Comment: or try this instead: ```var username = "{{ username|safe }}"```

Comment: Please add the comment suggestion to answer - it helped a lot

Comment: Is 'var' redundant? (i'm a pythonista and as you can see know little about js)

Answer (score 0):

Django already has a solution for this.
In your template,assuming you are extending the base template

```
....
{{ username|json_script:'username'}}
```

Then inside your javascript file

```
var username = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('username').textContent)
```

For more information about json script check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script