# CoffeeScript-like language written in Python

Tags: javascript, python, compiler-construction, coffeescript

Are there any languages targeting JavaScript (like CoffeeScript) and written in Python?  I found [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/), but it’s GWT of Python as I see.  I want a language that doesn’t need heavy runtime library and is able to be compiled to JavaScript.  I found [Mascara](http://www.mascaraengine.com/) also, and it very satisfies my requirements except it’s license.  CoffeeScript is ideal for me except it’s written in CoffeeScript itself.  I have to compile [CoffeeScript-like language] source codes into JavaScript statically in Python application.

Comment: @Lion Oh, thanks. I removed it.

Comment: "CoffeeScript-like" as in "it's just JavaScript"? Because that's the primary purpose of CoffeeScript: Do what JS does, just in a nicer way. Please elaborate on what defined this "non-JavaScript-language". If the sole problem with CoffeeScript is that it's not written in CoffeeScript, you can run from Python via [V8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/).

Comment: @delnan I wanted to say a language do what JavaScript does in a nicer way.

Comment: @Lion They are not "strictly prohibited" throughout the site, that is ludicrous.  However, the majority of the community seems to discourage them.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683462/best-way-to-integrate-python-and-javascript  -This might be helpful.

Comment: Do you exclude running a javascript engine from your python app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

PyvaScript: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/07/PyvaScript-Pythonic-syntax-for-your-browser

Pyjs: https://github.com/anandology/pyjs

Pyjamas: http://pyjs.org/

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at [pyjaco](http://pyjaco.org/) (python to javascript compiler).

Here's an example to get you started with manipulating the DOM in Python using jQuery:
https://github.com/chrivers/pyjaco/tree/devel/examples/jquery

Answer (score 0):

One part of Pyjamas is pyjs, which is decribed this way in the [project overview](http://pyjs.org/):

> pyjs translates Python code to Javascript by walking the Python abstract syntax tree and generating Javascript.

Sounds like it should fit the bill: no need to use the other parts of pyjamas you don't need.