# Reverse Transliteration from Language X to English

Tags: python, transliteration

I wanted to convert text in an Indian regional language "Kannada" to it's corrusponding pronunciation in English. E.g. the Kannada word ಅಂಗಸನ್ನೆ would be transliterated to "aṅgasanne" in English. I believe this process is called **reverse transliteration**. [Google Transliteration](http://www.google.com/intl/kn/inputtools/try/) does this the other way where you type text in English and corresponding Kannada text is generated, such that the pronunciation remains the same.

Is there any library that performs reverse transliteration -Kannada words to English, retaining pronounciation (preferably in python)?

Comment: [A similar question was asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297454/can-i-use-google-transliteration-in-python) - although they don't talk about Python libraries some of the answers do talk about using requests / Google's API.

Comment: Google's API does it the other way around. I needed Kannada to English.

Comment: PHP has a transliteration library which works either way.

Comment: @AjayH Didn't you try on your own? Using two arrays, one with kannada and other with latin letters, you can get the test and parse each letter and replace kannada letter with latin one. But you need to be careful with the mapping, as many-to-many mappings exist. For example, `ು` as well as `ಉ` will be replaced with u.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?