# Passing Variables In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html

so I currently have a JavaScript code that I run on my iPhone to pull its Accelerometer data. What I would like to do is Pass this data to my Mac Book Pro and use the variables in A python Script. The Variables are changing multiple times a second so it would need to repeatedly send the Variables. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Accelerometer JavaScript Test</h1>
<ul>
    <li>acceleration x: <span id="accelerationX"></span></li>
    <li>acceleration y: <span id="accelerationY"></span></li>
    <li>Motor Speed: <span id="speed"></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ondevicemotion = function(e){
        var x = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        var newx = x * 100
        var newy = y * 100
        var finalx = Math.round(x);
        var finaly = Math.round(y);
        document.getElementById("accelerationX").innerHTML = finalx
        document.getElementById("accelerationY").innerHTML = finaly
        speed = finalx * 10
        document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you already come up with something? You know you can send data through AJAX requests to a server running on the other side?

Comment: Thank you for responding and no I currently just have the javascript that picks up the variables, then am lost on how to get them to my mac .

Comment: Multiple times per second? Look into sockets & then web sockets.

Comment: Thank you for the idea I will definitely look into that!

Comment: Still not having any luck  with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I answered your question here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449596/using-socket-io-and-iphone-accelerometer/20452299#20452299

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do an ajax call. The first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code) question may help you.

The answer says:

All you need is to make an ajax request to your pythoncode. You can do this with jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, or use just javascript

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "~/pythoncode.py",
  data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});
```