# How to use javascript to send a request to call web.py behind code?

Tags: javascript, python, web.py

I have a button in my form.When user click it.It should send a request to the server to get a validate code.I am not sure how to realise it without refresh the page.Wait for your help,guys.Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to refresh the page, you should use Ajax as a request. Example using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "~/pythoncode.py",
   data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});
```

Taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175665/2854344

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Joao's answer, after making the AJAX request using jQuery, you can access it like using the POST function:

```
class FrontPage:
    def GET:
        ### Add some GET code here
    def POST:
        k = web.input()
        user_input = k['param']
        ### Do something with user_input and sends back using AJAX
```