# Call python function from JS

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to call a function in Python from my JavaScript code. I used the code explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code) but it does not work for me.

Here is my JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  
<script>
text ="xx";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "~/reverse_pca.py",
data: { param: text}
}).done(function(o) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(text);
});
```

Python Code:

```
import csv
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import matrix

def main():
    ...
    return x 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x=main()
    return x;
```

Do you know what is wrong with it?

Comment: `~/reverse_pca.py` is a relative path and it looks like it is meant to be an absolute path. Anyway, you should mention any error messages (because "does not work" can mean many things) and you should watch the web server logs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apart from the mentioned points and assuming you already have a proper setup to serve your python script and return the response. You should submit an asynchronous request, especially if the python code does some heavy computation.

```
function postData(input) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/reverse_pca.py",
        data: { param: input },
        success: callbackFunc
    });
}

function callbackFunc(response) {
    // do something with the response
    console.log(response);
}

postData('data to process');
```

If you only do some light computation and you have no problem working with a code deprecated as of jQuery 1.8, go with the synchronous approach. This is **not recommended** as it blocks the main thread.

```
function runPyScript(input){
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/reverse_pca.py",
        async: false,
        data: { param: input }
    });

    return jqXHR.responseText;
}

// do something with the response
response= runPyScript('data to process');
console.log(response);
```

Read more about it here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I'm getting '$' not defined. Please Help.

Comment: @SubtleCoder you need to import jQuery; see https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 19):

After searching for few hours, I ended up having the following, and it worked well. Hope this helps someone else in future.

**HTML and JS code: *loging.html*:**

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Flask Intro - login page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery 2.1.4.min.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Test Send Data">
    <!----------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function runPyScript(input){
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/login",
            async: false,
            data: { mydata: input }
        });

        return jqXHR.responseText;
    }

    $('#submitbutton').click(function(){
        datatosend = 'this is my matrix';
        result = runPyScript(datatosend);
        console.log('Got back ' + result);
    });

</script>
```

**Python code: *app.py*:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for,request
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hi"
@app.route("/index")

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
   message = None
   if request.method == 'POST':
        datafromjs = request.form['mydata']
        result = "return this"
        resp = make_response('{"response": '+result+'}')
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
        return resp
        return render_template('login.html', message='')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This helped.

Comment: `$` is not defined  
[error](https://imgur.com/a/3SS9qOL)
  
[error 2](https://imgur.com/a/jMldScV)

Comment: @henos The jQuery file didn't load. The original URL has an error. This part "jquery 2.1.4" should be "jquery-2.1.4" with the hyphen instead of the space.