# How do I connect my python code to my html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

[this is my html code for the search bar rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt4qE.png)

I want to connect my python code to this HTML code so that I can create a Youtuber object through the python code and apply different function. I want the Youtuber object to be created once the submit button has been pressed. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to call a python code when the `submit` button is pressed.

You could use this using **`AJAX`** or simple `JavaScript`. Check out the solutions suggested here.

1. [Call Python function from JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code)
2. [Call python function from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288722/call-python-function-from-js/32292424)

Comment: If this works out for you, please **`upvote`** and consider **`accepting`** this answer.

Comment: This is really interesting. Thanks!