# Using a python script by calling it through javascript

Tags: javascript, python

so I got this python script that removes duplicated files and sort them into folders corresponding to their extension .
what I want to do is when someone uploads a folder to the website than clicks a button the python script is called and starts , it creates a folder to store the sorted files for users to later download those files.

Comment: check similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288722/call-python-function-from-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call python function from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288722/call-python-function-from-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since javascript is client side, you'd need to set up some sort of backend that can handle the data sent by the user and then sorts it. moustafa linked a very good explanation, I reccomend reading that and you should be sorted.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, i'll take a look into it , much appreciated :)

Comment: Hello , so i've been going at it the whole day but i didn't manage to figure it out , does the linked post from moustafa works when the function is calling other functions?