# Executing Modular Python Script on Apache Webserver

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, webserver

I am trying to run a python script (adsb-exchange.py) on an Apache httpd webserver running on an EC2 instance. The script runs perfect from the AWS CLI, but when I try and run from a simple html page off the server I get:

#### Internal Server Error 500 - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

*Note, running a simple 'hello.py' script from the html page works fine.*

Everything is added under the /var/www/html directory and the httpd.conf file is updated to reflect the DocumentRoot path.

Index.html file:

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>Click the button below to start running the scipt...</p>
<form action="/adsb-exchange.py" method="post"> 
  <button>Start</button>
</form>
```

adsb-exchange.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python

#import Python modules
import cgi
import sys

cgi.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print

#application imports
import modules.get_config_vals as cfgvals
import modules.adsb_pull as ap
import modules.json2csv as j2c

#get payload params from adsb_config file
payload = cfgvals.get_payload()

#get the JSON pull frequency and runtime from config file
adsb_freq = cfgvals.get_pullfreq()

#send to adsb_pull module, create a JSON object file, and get the filename returned
f = ap.pull_data(payload, adsb_freq)

#convert JSON object file to CSV, output CSV file to directory
j2c.j2csv(f)

raw_input("Press Enter to exit")
```

The adsb-exchange.py file makes calls to various modules under the 'modules' folder via the /var/www/html/modules path, and each module includes the lines:
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
    print

GET and POST methods do not appear to impact the results. Output files are dumped to the same directory as adsb-exchange.py is in, for now.

Again, the script runs when executed directly from the ACL, but not when it is called from the index.html page.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code

Comment: Do you have set the execution permission on your python files? Can the apache server reach the file?

Comment: Yes, all files are given 755 permissions. The server can reach the hello.py file in the same folder, with the exact same permissions.