# Modify webpage element by calling Python function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

My `HTML` file looks like this:

```
Sum: <div id="sum">?</div>
```

And the corresponding JavaScript like this:

```
 function refresh(){
     //Wait for request from Amazon Gateway API, then replace 'sum' with result of 
 Python function
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://8qp45dk604.execute-api.us-east- 1.amazonaws.com/beta", true);

xhttp.send();
xhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
function processRequest(e){
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){

        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var a = response.a;
        var b = response.b;
        document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = 
        resultOfPythonFunction('sum.py', 'sum', a, b);
    }
}
    setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
}
```

What should I replace the line `resultOfPythonFunction('sum.py', 'sum', a, b);` with in order to modify the `div` with the result of a Python `sum` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Python function from Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code)

Comment: You'd need to make another AJAX call to your server to run the python function. Which begs the question, why are you making an AJAX request to get something to feed to another AJAX request? Do all that on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The browser can't execute python code. To do what you're asking, you would have to set up a python back end that you could send HTTP POST requests to that would perform `sum` on your request body, and then send back the result. Some common tools for this are [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), and [pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/).

You could then grab this result and set it to the `div` in the way you did before.