# Access python method from plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this python method shown below in a separate file and want to access and get value using plain js *(no frame works used.)* is there any way i can achieve this?

```
def myPythonCode :
        ....
        ...
        return somevalue
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: How and where are you running your javascript code, how and where are you running your python code?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code

Comment: Do you know about a client (JavaScript) - server (Python) side communication? It is best to do some research about how to do a client-server side communication through a web browser (or electron apps) with JavaScript first.

Comment: You can try Ajax.

Comment: Plain JS answer in [Call Python function from JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code) is [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175651/557019)

Comment: for this i should use flask and run it as server right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python wrapper for google V8 engine called [**PyV8**](https://pypi.org/project/PyV8/)

It act as a bridge between the Python and JavaScript objects, and support to hosting Google's v8 engine in a python script.

Comment: i dont want to do any changes in python code. just plain js. i want to use scipy.spatial package, since js doesnt have anything. i used python for that and now i want to integrate python code with my plain js