# How to run python function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have a problem in calling my python function from my javascript file.

I'm using a simple server with `python3 -m http.server`, so no actual backend..my javascripts are in the front end.

I have a python file called `write.py` it has a function that I want to execute from my javascript file

write.py file:

```py
def save_vit(text,name):
    f = open(name + ".xml", "w+")
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
```

the javascript part that i have tried:(but didn't work)

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "write.py",
        data: { text: xmlDoc,name: name}});
```

**xmlDoc** is a string that has an xml document.

**name** is a variable that has the name of the file for the python function.

So my question is, what am I missing to call `write.py` from my js file or how to call it if this approach is wrong?

Comment: You cannot do it like that. I suggest to use a micro web framework in python like Flask. Then you can relate directories to run codes and functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Python function from JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code)

Comment: @RobertMoskal i have seen it before i post this question, my problem is a bit different.

Comment: Abdel, it's not different!  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are using http.server to serve the content of a folder, as files, not to execute them, so in the best case scenario, http.server will respond with the content of the `write.py` file instead of executing it.

You need to create a webserver that has a endpoint where the code of write.py is integrated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a POST http request to run a python script.

You need to have the python script running on a server, that is able to take restful API calls, to run the script and return a value.

For example, you can run a small flask app that takes in your POST route, which runs a script and returns the value of the script back to the client that accessed the POST route.

Comment: so, there is no any simpler way to do it without having another server that has my python function on it?

Comment: the _restful_ part of your answer is not necessary at all. You just need to send an http request.

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanEl-Feraly you need to have a server or some micro framework that is able to handle http requests. A python script alone cant interpret a POST request, which is why I recommend flask since its lightweight and easy to setup

Comment: i know a server or micro framework would solve it, but i wanted a way(if possible and exist) that solves it without having an actual backend to call the python function @alex067

Comment: There are several ways to communicate with services & micro services, and the most common is via api calls, which require a framework able to handle http requests.  The other method is via messaging, but this is way too complex for something like this. Basically you would send messages to a message broker, and your python script needs to be able to fetch the message.

Answer (score 1):

Python is running on the *server* side ... JavaScript is running on the *client* side.

So, the only way for JavaScript to ask for a Python routine to be run is through an asynchronous AJAX request which you will have to build.

Comment: the problem is, i'm not using an actual Python backend..i created python server using this line only "python3 -m http.server" , the python file i want to call, is in the directory where i used this line "python3 -m http.server"