# how to run python function which is called from JavaScript where the input is passed from html text box

Tags: javascript, python, html, robotframework

I have written html code for a text box, when I enter input to html text box, this input should be passed to JavaScript variable.
Inside JavaScript I called a python function and this python function should receive the input from html text box input which is passed to JavaScript variable and get executed.
Anyone help me with this...

Comment: How do you call the Python function from JavaScript?

Comment: As a child process
const spawner = require('child_process').spawn;
        const data_to_pass_in=input;
        console.log('Read input:',data_to_pass_in);
        const python_process=spawner ('python',['./name.py',input,data_to_pass_in]);

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar query asked on this platform 9 years ago. Some folks have provided a solution to make an AJAX call to your python code. Please have a look at that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code) might be helpful to you in some way. Thank you.