# Using python modules in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, binding

Is it possible to create a glue that makes it possible for python modules (more specifically, library bindings) to be used in node.js? Some of the data structures can be directly mapped to V8 objects - e.g. array, dict.

More importantly - would that be a more elegant way to create bindings than manually or through FFI. In short, would it be worth it?

Comment: Theoretically possible, but I've never heard of this being implemented, and it's unlikely to be worthwhile.

Comment: maybe something from this question will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683462/best-way-to-integrate-python-and-javascript

Comment: I saw that, but this is a question if python modules can/should be ported to node.js rather than an actual problem that requires a JS <-> Python bridge.

Answer (score 3):

Try this node.js module, that is a bridge: [Node-Python](https://npmjs.org/package/node-python),

NOTE: The Project is 7 years old and still stuck at v0.4. A lot of functionality like converting between Python and Node arrays is still missing. It may be safe to assume that it's no longer supported by its original author(s)

Answer (score 2):

[Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) does a fine job at this. It allows you to write a Python script and then call the routines from Node.js, which can be used to easily create bindings with python modules.

Comment: Note on that - it uses IronPython, .NET's python implementation, and for Edge.js, the docs say (as of 2018-03-14) that this has only been tested on Windows.