# Running python library in a nodejs environment

Tags: python, node.js

I have a lot of microservices in my app. All of them are nodejs (typescript).
Recently I had to add a new library that is written in Python.
7 nodejs microservices of my app will need to use it.

How can I run this Python library inside my app? I can expose a REST API in Python and speak with it from nodejs. But this will break the microservice most common principle: every service needs to be totally independent and not be depends on other services.

How can such situation be solved?

Comment: My intuition tells me you misunderstood that principle...And i would like to hear the explanation as well..

Comment: Ain't it quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15055630/4636715 or am I missing something?