# How do I integrate a Python application with a javascript application?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a GUI based Python application at which the user loads airport data manually from an existing data base with longitude, latitude, altitude, etc. once the data is loaded it gets used elsewhere in the script.

I want to be able to load the data from a google maps map on a web based application directly into the python application after the user clicks on any given airport. I have the javascript web based application ready and it's working as expected. I am getting the data stored but I am not sure how to make the connection between the Python application and the javascript application in real time.

I would like to know conceptually what is the best approach I should use.

Comment: Is this tkinter? Maybe use pywebview.

Comment: stackoverflow is for asking about specific issues in specific code. Questions that ask for recommendations (such as strategies or "best" something) are out of scope.

Comment: Try looking at [How can I integrate Python and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683462/how-can-i-integrate-python-and-javascript)